# Running multiple commands in a batch script for wsl

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a batch script which is used to launch 2 bots in WSL at Windows login.

```
C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c "/home/roughnecks/go/bin/irchuu"
C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c "node /home/roughnecks/bots/Birba/birba.js"
```

My problem is that only the first line runs, I guess because it outputs stuff in the terminal and "birba.js" doesn't fire unless I "ctrl-c" in terminal, exiting irchuu.

I already tried different combinations, like using "nohup command &" or "command 2>&1 &" but nothing is working as expected and I need help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you try : `wsl -e node /home/roughnecks/bots/Birba/birba.js` ?

Comment: It's the same stuff; only the first bot runs, while for the second to fire I have to "ctrl-c" in cmd to stop execution of the first one.

Comment: I also tried: "start cmd.exe /c <first command>
start cmd.exe /c <second command>" but the cmd prompts stay open and I want them to go away...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows `bash` does not seem to support `&` to fork a command and continue. 
From this [Windows-related question](https://superuser.com/a/591084/205056) `START /B` was suggested which seems to work:

```
START /B C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c "/home/roughnecks/go/bin/irchuu"
C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c "node /home/roughnecks/bots/Birba/birba.js"
```

Comment: Hi. If I go that route, irchuu doesn't run - shell continues and just loads birba. Same if I start birba first... I only get an "init" process in task manager but no "node" (and irchuu loads).

Comment: There is an answer to a Windows-related question here: https://superuser.com/a/591084/205056 - you could try to prepend `START /B`

Comment: Thanks  @Jonas Eberle, it's solved finally: start /B C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c "/home/roughnecks/go/bin/irchuu" is what I used. If you want to add your answer I'll mark the question solved. https://stackoverflow.com/users/2819581/jonas-eberle